# Table charts de Google solo me devuelve una fila de mi REST API

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rest, google-chart-api

Hola estoy tratando de mostrar los datos de una API REST en un Table Charts de Google con Angular pero al momento de ejecutar el codigo solo me devuelve el ultimo registro quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que me muestre todos los registros.
Gracias de antemano

[image: Solo me devuelve el ultimo registro que es de China]

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe((res: Data[]) => {
      Object.entries(res.countries).forEach(([y,v] )=> {





      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {



        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Nombre Pais');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Nro de casos');


       data.addRows([
       [y,v['total_cases']],
        ]);
      console.log([v['total_cases']]);
        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'),);

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '50%', height: '100%',page: 'enable',
        pageSize: 50}); }});

    }
    )}
      }
```

la estructura de mi JSON es la siguiente:

```
{"countries":{"USA":{"country_name":"USA","total_cases":1735029,"total_recovered":481988,"total_deaths":101285},"Brazil":{"country_name":"Brazil","total_cases":394507,"total_recovered":158593,"total_deaths":24600},"Russia":{"country_name":"Russia","total_cases":370680,"total_recovered":142208,"total_deaths":3968},"Spain":{"country_name":"Spain","total_cases":283339,"total_recovered":196958,"total_deaths":27117},"UK":{"country_name":"UK","total_cases":267240,"total_recovered":null,"total_deaths":37460},"China":{"country_name":"China","total_cases":82993,"total_recovered":78280,"total_deaths":4634}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas creando cada vez el `DataTable` en cada iteracion de `entries`, asi que se sobrescribe y deja solo el ultimo.

Deberia ser asi:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe((res: Data[]) => {

    let drawTable = () => {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'), );

      data.addColumn('string', 'Nombre Pais');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Nro de casos');



      Object.entries(res.countries).forEach(([y, v]) => {
        data.addRows([
          [y, v['total_cases']],
        ]);
        console.log([v['total_cases']]);

      });

      table.draw(data, {
        showRowNumber: true,
        width: '50%',
        height: '100%',
        page: 'enable',
        pageSize: 50
      });

    }




    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['table']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  })
}
}
```

Comment: Gracias!!! funciono